# What's better for a physical layout of HDD and SSD drives in a computer case?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, desktop-computer, temperature

When you set up a multi-drive desktop computer, what is better: the SSD drives above the HDD drives, the SSD drives below the HDD drives or it's absolutely indifferent?

I've seen that SSD get warmer than HDD, so I think it's better to place the SSD drives over the HDD drives since hot air goes up and would warm more the SSD in the other way around. Moreover, SSDs are smaller than HDDs so they let the air flow better than HDDs.

Here is a picture of an example of placing an SSD above and HDD:
[image]

Comment: It doesn't matter.  The SSD doesn't generate any heat and the hdd generates so little heat it doesn't matter

Comment: Neither setup would make any sort of difference.

Comment: This question makes me wish I had a thermal camera ;p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Practically speaking, with just two drives it should not make a difference on an actively cooled system.

If your system simply cooled itself on convection, sure, this may be the case.

The 'minimal'/Standard ATX layout is designed to *pull* air through the front, sometimes with a front fan, over the CPU (With its own fan and heatsink) and out through the PSU. You also have a large intake that should (vaguely) evenly let air pass over the drives and the drives are not blocking each other's airflow.

[image]

As such, the effects of drive placement are minimal since cooler air is pulled/pushed over the drives, and the effects of these are relatively minimal, as would the heat sinking effects of the metal sides of the drive bay.

I *would* place them somewhat apart for ease of maintenance, but in that case, under normal circumstances, I'd just go with whatever option that makes you feel better. Don't forget, that system can handle up to 6 hard drives, so the cooling setup should be able to handle that easily.

---

I borrowed a cheap thermal camera (a Seek) and decided to do some *science*. I'd note the amount of heat generated would depend on the drives (as you'd see), the case and other factors. This can't be taken as a *definitive* answer, though it builds on my answer. In all these cases, I ran the system for half an hour to reach a steady state, under normal circumstances. I probably should have run a constant load on all the drives etc etc etc, but this is my regular system, and I was simply curious.

Lets start with the original setup - a 250gb drive, a 3tb drive and a 256gb SSD all stacked together.  The system had been running all day at that point though, so meh, not a good data point, other than as a rough idea of how the drive temperatures are.

Oddly enough, while I moved away the 250gb drive for other reasons, its in direct airflow behind a fan. See how much cooler it is.

[image]

And SSD on top of 3tb drive. Moved the HDD down to keep overall heat generation about even.

[image]

And with the SSD below.

In both cases the SSD runs *considerably cooler* than the 3TB drive

[image]

So practically speaking, its at most a few degrees difference, and it matters more on what the drives are and their overall position relative to any fans in the case, than their positions relative to each other. There's plenty of space for air to flow.

To close, this is a photo of my whole system. Hard drives are not exactly the hottest part in a PC.

[image]

So chances are, no, it wouldn't particularly matter. Spacing out the drives seems to have more of an impact than location.

Comment: Awesome research, nice! :)

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no performance or temperature difference with any of your proposed arrangements. Just pick the one that looks the prettiest.